# Rails: ActionText has_rich_text returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

I've added ActionText into my Rails 5.2 app, according to [this tutorial](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/using-action-text-in-a-rails-5-2-application). I performed installation, migration and added *action_text_rich_texts* column. I also updated my model:

```
class LiveEvent < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :description_long
end
```

However has_rich_text helper seems to not working. When I try to initialize new record this way:

```
@live_event = LiveEvent.new(live_event_params)
```

description_long attribute returns nil because of this helper. Which crashes my app due to the validation constrains.

Strong param permission for description_long it's also not a case since that attribute was permitted before. This error occurs even if I want to add new record directly through the Rails console:

```
le = LiveEvent.new(description_long: 'test')
le[:description_long] // returns nil
```

Maybe there is no established binding between *action_text_rich_texts* and my LiveEvent model? I'm not sure what it the possible cause of this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: try `@live_event.description_long.body.to_html`, btw the way you get attribute is wrong, it should be `le.description_long` which will return `ActionText::RichText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionText` is providing polymorphic association with Model we mention `has_rich_text`.

So when we define `has_rich_text` is actually we are defining an association, like we do `has_one`, 'has_many', `belongs_to`.

So when you write

```rb
@live_event = LiveEvent.new(description_long: 'test')
```

It will create a new instance of `ActionText::RichText` model and assign the `"text"` in the body column as instance of `ActionText::Content`. So what ever value we assigned to `description_long` as rich text will automatically wrapped into into a div tag `<div class="trix-content">`.

Here is the example.

```rb
pry(main)> e = Email.new(content: "Asd")
=> #<Email:0x00007fd612746018
 id: nil,
 user_id: nil,
 subject: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>

pry(main)> e.content
=> #<ActionText::RichText:0x00007fd612745c80
 id: nil,
 name: "content",
 body: #<ActionText::Content "<div class=\"trix-conte...">,
 record_type: "Email",
 record_id: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>

pry(main)> e[:content]
=> nil

pry(main)> e.content.body.to_s
=> "<div class=\"trix-content\">\n  Asd\n</div>\n"
```

so `content` in this example is not actually a column but it's a association. same way `description_long` in your example is an `association` not a column.

Please fine the note below "Note: you don't need to add a content field to your messages table." here in this guide https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html